# How to test for empty recordset

Tags: php, unixodbc

I'm using PHP ODBC library to connect to a MSSQL 2008 server (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php).

Some of my stored procedures do not return record sets (e.g. they just do an insert or update). I would like to be able to handle output gracefully in this situation. After the database call is made, the output is injected into an array which is returned to the application for processing. Here are the key parts of the code (excluding error handling etc):

```
$sql_result = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
    $resultArray[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

If `$sql_result` has executed successfully, but does not contain a record set (as it would following an insert or update) then `odbc_fetch_array` triggers this warning:

> Warning: odbc_fetch_row(): No tuples available at this result index

Ideally, I'd like to test `$sql_result` first to see if it contains an empty record set, but every obvious attempt I've tried always leads to the same warning message.

Anyone got a neat way of checking to see if `$sql_result` is empty?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a simple way using the PHP odbc API. Usually you would use different functions to process statements that return values such as SELECT vs those like UPDATE that do not.

If this is a utility that runs arbitrary statements you could parse the statement.

This isn't an empty result set, it's no result set at all, you might be able to tell the difference by examining the result in a debugger or using var_dump.